# FileLock for two exclusive processed

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-locking

Windows supports [LockFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfile) function for applying exclusive locks on a file, and the [LockFileEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfileex) functions for applying an exclusive locks and shared read for all processes.

Is it possible to have ProcessA apply an exclusive lock, and then allow *Only* ProcessA *And* ProcessB to read the file, while at the time, no other process - outside those two processes - would have read access on the locked file?

Comment: the docs seem to talk about access to the file, not about read or write, unless i am wrong. having read access to a locked file would seem to be a bit useless.

Comment: From the doc: *Locking a portion of a file for shared access denies all processes write access to the specified region of the file, including the process that first locks the region. All processes can read the locked region.*

Comment: thought you were asking about exclusive locks - perhaps write a little pseudo code to illustrate what you are asking - doesn't need to be windows api

Comment: "*Is it possible to ...*" - AFAIK, not with `LockFile/Ex`, no.  But ProcessA could lock the file exclusively with read sharing enabled, but allow security access to only another specific user, and then ProcessB could open the file for read-only access as that user.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Doc：[LockFileEx function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfileex)

> Exclusive locks cannot overlap an existing locked region of a file.
> Shared locks can overlap a locked region provided locks held on that
> region are shared locks. A shared lock can overlap an exclusive lock
> if both locks were created using the same file handle. When a shared
> lock overlaps an exclusive lock, the only possible access is a read by
> the owner of the locks.

In my opinion, Exclusive lock doesn't allow read and write operations.Shared lock allows only read operation.

If the file is set `Exclusive lock` with LockFileEx function, all other processes will be denied both read and write access.
If the file is set `Shared lock`with LockFileEx function, all processes can read the locked region.
If the file is set `shared lock` and `exclusive lock` at the same time, the only possible access is a read by the owner of the locks.